# Add nested dictionaries on matching keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary, such as:

```
{'A1': {'T1': [1, 3.0, 3, 4.0], 'T2': [2, 2.0]}, 'A2': {'T1': [1, 0.0, 3, 5.0], 'T2': [2, 3.0]}}
```

What I want to do is sum each sub dictionary, to obtain this:

```
A1 A2  A1 A2
T1+T1  T2+T2 (ignore the first entry of the list)
 [3.0, 5.0, 9.0] <<<< output
   1    2    3
res 3.0 + 0.0 = 3.0  and 2.0 + 3.0 = 5.0 and  5.0 + 4.0 = 9.0
```

How can I do this? I've tried a for, but I've created a big mess

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) in a list comprehension, and `sum` the resulting `Counter` objects:

```
from collections import Counter
d = {'A1': {'T1': 3.0, 'T2': 2.0}, 'A2': {'T1': 0.0, 'T2': 3.0}} 

l = (Counter(i) for i in d.values())
sum(l, Counter())
# Counter({'T1': 3.0, 'T2': 5.0})
```

For `sum` to work here, I've defined an empty `Counter()` as the `start` argument, so `sum` expects other `Counter` objects.

To get only the values, you can do:

```
sum(l, Counter()).values()
# dict_values([3.0, 5.0])
```

Comment: @SportsCodes if the question is another I suggest you to ask it separately, and accepts the here proposed answers. Otherwise is seems as the current answers are not answering the question.

Comment: it's not another question, I copied the wrong input

Answer (score 0):

you could use a list comprehension with `zip`:

```
d = {'A1': {'T1': 3.0, 'T2': 2.0}, 'A2': {'T1': 0.0, 'T2': 3.0}} 
[sum(e) for e in zip(*(e.values() for e in d.values()))]
```

output:

```
[3.0, 5.0]
```

this will work if your [python version is >= 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)

also, you can use 2 `for` loops:

```
r = {}
for dv in d.values():
    for k, v in dv.items():
        r.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
result = [sum(v) for v in r.values()]
print(result)
```

output:

```
[3.0, 5.0]
```

---

**after your edit**

you could use:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

sum_t1, sum_t2 = list(list(map(sum, zip(*t))) for t in zip(*[e.values() for e  in d.values()]))
[i for t in zip_longest(sum_t1[1:], sum_t2[1:]) for i in t if i is not None]
```

output:

```
[3.0, 5.0, 6, 9.0]
```

Comment: @SportsCodes I think you also have to update the expected output

Comment: it's the same! :)

Comment: Not working! TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Comment: @SportsCodes you can cehck now my update, but your desired output is wrong should be `[3.0, 5.0, 6, 9.0]`, you forgot 6 (3 + 3)  from T1